# How to check regEx for "#" using Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

In the particular textbox i want avoid the "#" using regular expression. But i can't find the regEx for "#" alone. And other special characters are accepted.

```
 var regExCheck= new RegExp("#");
if(updatedCoverageTypeName.test(regExCheck))
                {
                    //code should implement
                }
```

The aboce code is not working.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is incorrect so update it.

```
if(regExCheck.test(updatedCoverageTypeName)){
// -^^^^^^^^^------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----

}
```

Also `new RegExp("#")` is equivalent to `/#/`, so you can directly use the regex instead of parsing a string.

---

For checking `#` is present in the string there is a better way using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

```
if(updatedCoverageTypeName.indexOf('#') > -1){

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Change it to:

```
  var regExCheck= new RegExp("/#/g");
 if(updatedCoverageTypeName.test(regExCheck))
            {
                //code should implement
            }
```